# Performance issue with order by clause with PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-performance

I would like to overcome an issue which occurs only in case with order by clause.

Details:
I am trying to insert into a temporary table 50 rows from a joined table ordered by a modification time column which is inserted by the current time so it is ordered ascending.

Each table has a multicolumn index on the following columns: `PRIMARY KEY(SystemID, ObjectID, ElementID,  ModificationTime)`

Statement:

```
sqlString := 'INSERT INTO ResultTable ('
             'SELECT * '
             'FROM "TABLE" a '
             '   LEFT OUTER JOIN "TABLE_Text" l1031 '
             '      ON a.ModificationTime = l1031.ModificationTime '
             '         AND a.SystemID = l1031.SystemID '
             '         AND a.ObjectID = l1031.ObjectID '
             '         AND a.ElementID = l1031.ElementID '
             '         AND l1031.LCID = 1031 '
             '   LEFT OUTER JOIN ( '
             '      SELECT * AS CommentNumber '
             '      FROM "TABLE_Comment" v1 '
             '      GROUP BY v1.ModificationTime, v1.SystemID, v1.ObjectID, v1.ElementID '
             '   ) c '
             '      ON a.ModificationTime = c.ModificationTime '
             '         AND a.SystemID = c.SystemID '
             '         AND a.ObjectID = c.ObjectID '
             '         AND a.ElementID = c.ElementID '
             'WHERE a.ModificationTime BETWEEN $1 AND $2 '
             '  AND ( a.Enabled = 1 ) '
             'ORDER BY a.ModificationTime DESC '
             'LIMIT 50)';

EXECUTE sqlString USING StartTime,EndTime;
```

[image]

Execution Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/S96g (Obfuscated)

If I remove the order by clause I get the following results:

[image]

Which is pointing me to a problem with the sorting. Is there any way that I could improve the performance with order by clause?

To make the problem more transparent I ran a long run test where you can see that with order by clause the performance is linearly getting worse:

[image]

Postgresql version: "PostgreSQL 11.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

Istalled by: With  EnterpriseDB One-click installer from EDB's offical site.

Postgresql.conf changes: Used pgtune suggestions:

```
# DB Version: 11 
# OS Type: windows 
# DB Type: desktop 
# Total Memory (RAM): 8 GB 
# CPUs num: 4 
# Connections num: 25 
# Data Storage: hdd 
max_connections = 25 
shared_buffers = 512MB 
effective_cache_size = 2GB 
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB 
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5 
wal_buffers = 16MB 
default_statistics_target = 100 
random_page_cost = 4 
work_mem = 8738kB 
min_wal_size = 100MB 
max_wal_size = 1GB 
max_worker_processes = 4 
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2 
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

Operating System: Windows 10 x64, Version: 1607

Comment: Unrelated, but executing dynamic sql is amazingly slow, and I see nothing in your query requiring it, so if you want to improve performance that's something else to change.